# C : create string in char array from concatenation

Tags: c, arrays, concatenation

I want to create a string in char array from concatenation in `C`
Example I want to do something similar to this

```
...
...
#define version "1.0"

char message[] = "Software version" + version + "\n"
...
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of the `+`s: consecutive string constants get concatenated by the compiler.

Comment: Preprocessor macros traditionally have all upper-case names, to distinguish them from e.g. variable and function names.

Comment: @Kninnug wow I wonder how I didn't think of this before :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know But I decide to drop this because I love the camelCase and I hate too much underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C has a feature to concatenate string literals during compilation, by just having white-space between the literals. Meaning you could do e.g.

```
char message[] = "Software version" version "\n"
```